# delete entity in onetomany relationship jpa

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, wildfly

i have 3 tables: customer, rent, and edition. where customer have one or more rents, and edition have one or more rents. rent have 2 foreign keys (customerId, editionId) and one primary key (rentId), i am trying to delete one customer, but i have an error that the fk of customerId are still in the rent table. i first delete all rents from the customer's listRent. Here is the delete method (email is the customerId from rent´s table):

```
    public boolean delete(String email){
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("tutorial");
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

        Customer customer= entityManager.find(Customer.class, email);
        if(customer!=null){
            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
            for (Rent rent :customer.getRentList()) {
                entityManager.remove(rent);
            }
            entityManager.remove(customer);
            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
            entityManager.close();
            entityManagerFactory.close();
            return true;
        }
        entityManager.close();
        entityManagerFactory.close();
        return false;
    }
```

but still have the error:

```
javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction (...)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: update o delete in «customer» violates the foreign key «fkgft5yuturjnobc97u2x1464b» in the table «rent»
```

here is the customer entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Customer")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="lastName")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="Gender")
    private String gender;

    @Column(name="age")
    private Integer age;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Rent> rentList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Customer(){
    }

    public Customer(String email, String firstName, String lastName, String gender, Integer age) {
        this.email = email;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.age = age;
    }
```

and rent entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Rent")
public class Rent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="rent_id")
    private Integer rentId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="email")
    private Customer customer;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="edition_id")
    private Edition edition;

    @Column(name="renting_date")
    private String rentingDate;

    public Rent(){
    }

    public Rent(String rentingDate) {
        this.rentingDate = rentingDate;
    }
```

I'm skipping the edit table just because is the same that customer with other attributes, and the owner of both tables is rent. i try delete directly in postgresql and works when i delete the rent table and then customer table, but for some reason, i cant not delete with jpa

i am ussing postgresql 13, wildfly 23 and hibernate.

Comment: Sometimes it is just easier to have a "deleted" flag on an entity.

Comment: you mean some query? or some method inside the customer class?

Comment: You are using `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` which should automatically delete all child `Rent`when deleting the `Customer`entity. Have you tried it?

Comment: yes, and give me the same error, that was why i deleted the rent manually

Comment: what happens if you start the transaction `entityManager.getTransaction().begin();` before the instruction `Customer customer= entityManager.find(Customer.class, email);`?

Comment: still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

There are tests in Hibernate(https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/hibernate-core/src/test/java/org/hibernate/test/bytecode/enhancement/cascade/CascadeDeleteCollectionTest.java) that exercise exactly this scenario so there must be something wrong with your setup. It's a bit fishy that you build up the `EntityManagerFactory` manually since you run on Wildfly. My guess, you are packaging a custom old version of Hibernate into your WAR which is then used which might be buggy. Try using `<scope>provided</scope>` for the Hibernate dependency.